# Executar o gancho 'beforeUpdate' somente uma vez no VueJS

Tags: javascript, loop, vue.js

Tenho uma um bloco de código dentro do gancho `beforeUpdate()` da instância do Vue, e ela está executando várias vezes seguidas.

A minha dúvida é:

É normal o gancho `beforeUpdate()` ser chamado várias vezes?? Se não, como faço para evitar esse loop que ele fica rodando??

```
beforeUpdate () {
  this.pageTimeGround = this.initTimeGroud(this.timeGround)
  let maxTime = this.pageTimeGround[this.pageTimeGround.length - 1]
  let minTime = this.pageTimeGround[0]
  let maxMin = maxTime.split(':')[0] * 60 + maxTime.split(':')[1] * 1
  let minMin = minTime.split(':')[0] * 60 + minTime.split(':')[1] * 1
  for (let i = 0; i < this.taskDetail.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.taskDetail[i].length; j++) {
      let startMin = this.taskDetail[i][j].dateStart.split(':')[0] * 60 + this.taskDetail[i][j].dateStart.split(':')[1] * 1
      let endMin = this.taskDetail[i][j].dateEnd.split(':')[0] * 60 + this.taskDetail[i][j].dateEnd.split(':')[1] * 1
      if (startMin < minMin || endMin > maxMin) {
        this.taskDetail[i].splice(j, 1)
        j--
        continue
      }
      let difMin = endMin - startMin
      this.taskDetail[i][j].styleObj = {
        height: difMin * 50 / 60 + 'px',
        top: ((startMin - (this.pageTimeGround[0].split(':')[0] * 60 + this.pageTimeGround[0].split(':')[1] * 1)) * 50 / 60) + 25 + 'px',
        backgroundColor: this.color[~~(Math.random() * this.color.length)]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Esse código é da lib [vue-schedule](https://github.com/jayZOU/vue-schedule), e está dentro do e atualmente ela está dentro do `created()`, porém necessito que sempre que ocorra alguma alteração no `data()` da instância a DOM seja re-renderizada pois estou trabalhando com uma agenda de eventos e com notificações através do Socket.io

Comment: adicione seu código para analisarmos

Comment: Adicionado o código @FelipeDuarte

Comment: Bom somente com o trecho da função creio que não será possível identificar o problema, pois a estrutura de funcionamento do beforeUpdate é ampla. Básicamente ele é requisitado antes da mudança no data, porém ele escuta todas as mudanças, ou seja, se em meu escopo eu aciono uma função que altera 3 variáveis no data, o beforeUpdate será executado 3 vezes, pode ser que seja seu caso.

Comment: É exatamente isso que acontece, estou tentando achar uma solução e não estou conseguindo...

Comment: você previsa realmente usar beforeUpdate ? ele é muito genérico, você precisa executar ele quando? é somente depois um função ou várias? se puder adicionar a função que altera o data seria interessante

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema, o que acontecia era o seguinte: Ele estava renderizando o componente antes mesmo de concluir a montagem e os cálculos de altura e largura para aplicar o estilo, e para testar isso eu coloquei um `v-if` com um `boolean` com valor false e com um `setTimeout()` de apenas 100ms de atraso na renderização ele funcionou certo. Agora só preciso fazer o código de uma maneira que o tempo de atraso não esteja fixo. Agradeço imensamente pela sua atenção e disponibilidade em ajudar @FelipeDuarte...